# indexOf- getting '0' though the item is present more than once

Tags: jquery, arrays, validation, input, compare

I have to create an array from the dynamically inputs in my form, and check if there identical values.

Example of the inputs:

```
<input type="text" data-index="0" id="inputMail0" class="signup-input text-value" name="email[0]" placeholder="e.g. example@url.com">
<input type="text" data-index="1" id="inputMail1" class="signup-input text-value" name="email[1]" placeholder="e.g. example@url.com">
```

I use the following js code:

```
   function validation(value,element){
      $('form *').removeClass('ignore');
        var map = [];
        $('.email input[type="text"]').each(function() {
            if($(this).val()!="") {
                map.push($(this).val())
            }
        });
        $('.email input[type="text"]').each(function(){
            if (map.indexOf($(this).val())>=0){
                console.log($(this).val())
            }
        });
```

The code doesn't get the necessary result.

Comment: Where is your class email?

Comment: You seem confused - an index of `0` means the item was found in the first position of the array. `-1` means that it was not found.

Comment: @ tabz100- in the div which is parent of the inputs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to merge with one each loop

```
var map = [];

$('.email input[type="text"]').each(function(){
            if (map.indexOf($(this).val()) == -1){ // check the value exists
                map.push($(this).val())
            }
            else{
                // already exists
            }
 });
```